# UWP custom media controls not working

Tags: xaml, custom-controls, mediaelement, uwp

below is the XAML code for my UWP app media element , but its not giving the customized media controls, why is that?

```
     <MediaElement x:Name="Media" Grid.Row="1" AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" >
            <MediaElement.TransportControls>
                <MediaTransportControls Background="#FFF5F509" Foreground="#FF0625EA"/>
            </MediaElement.TransportControls>

     </MediaElement>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `MediaTransportControls` has `Background` and `Foreground` properties, but setting these properties won't affect the appearance of `MediaTransportControls`. Because by default MediaTransportControls uses `ColorBrush` defined in `ThemeResource`.

You can find `MediaTransportControls`'s template at [MediaTransportControls styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt414180.aspx) or in ***generic.xaml*** (typical in ***`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic`***) search "MediaTransportControls".

Form its template, we can find its `Background` and `Foreground` are set to some `ThemeResource` such as:

```
<Grid x:Name='ControlPanelGrid'
            Background='{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}'
            VerticalAlignment='Bottom'
            RenderTransformOrigin='0.5,0.5'>
```

If we want to use `MediaTransportControls`'s `Background` and `Foreground` properties to customize media transport control, we need set `Background` or `Foreground` to `{TemplateBinding Foreground}`. For some property, such as `Background`, it may be easy. You just need find the `Grid` named "ControlPanelGrid" and change its `Background` like following:

```
<Grid x:Name='ControlPanelGrid'
            Background='{TemplateBinding Background}'
            VerticalAlignment='Bottom'
            RenderTransformOrigin='0.5,0.5'>
```

But for the property like `Foreground`, it's complex. Because the `Foreground` is defined in a lot of sub `Style` and they have different value in different Styles. And in WinRT, it doesn't support a Binding usage for Setter.Value. So you have to set `{TemplateBinding Foreground}` one by one. Here I use `AppBarButton` in `<CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>` for example:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="StopButton"
              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              Icon="Stop"
              MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="1"
              Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
              Visibility="Collapsed" />
<AppBarButton x:Name="RewindButton"
              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="2"
              Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
              Visibility="Collapsed">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEB9E;" />
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
...
```

After this, you can put this style in `<Application.Resources>` and give this `style` a `x:key` like `<Style x:Key="MyMediaTransportControlsStyle" TargetType="MediaTransportControls">`. Then you can use this new style in `MediaTransportControls`:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement"
              Margin="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
              AutoPlay="False">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls Background="Red" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource MyMediaTransportControlsStyle}" IsStopButtonVisible="True" IsStopEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardEnabled="True" IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True" IsFastRewindEnabled="True" />
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

The `MediaTransportControls` will use the color you set in its `Background` and `Foreground` property.

[image]

Comment: really well explained and wonderful answer man, really appreciate it thanks :) ill get back to you if i have more questions regarding this :)

Comment: I am trying your method but using **10.0.10586.0/Generic**. There's a new AppBarButtonStyle where there's no Foreground property set. All the AppBarButtons are having this Style. If I set myself a Foreground Property, it gives an error and when running the App, the debugger makes it crash. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @LayaleMatta: AFAIK, the styles of `MediaTransportControls` in 10.0.10240.0 and 10.0.10586.0 are the same. My method should also work in 10.0.10586.0. If you still have problem with my method you can ask a new question with the XAML code you used. Thanks.