# MediaElement Customize 'TimeRemainingElement' in MediaTransportControls UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, uwp, mediaelement

I have changed the Background and Foreground Color of the MediaElement's MediaTransportControls using this solution [UWP custom media controls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393578/uwp-custom-media-controls-not-working)

Now I want to

- change the place of the **'TimeRemainingElement'** and put it on the left of the Slider.
- make the time show as **00:00** not 0:00:00

Is it possible to do that? Any idea how to do it?

- 1 more question: Is it possible to remove the **"Cast to Device"** icon/option from the MediaTransportControls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible. As I've mentioned in my previous answer in [UWP custom media controls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33730953/5506161), we can edit [MediaTransportControls styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt414180.aspx) to achieve what you want.

> change the place of the **'TimeRemainingElement'** and put it on the left of the Slider.

`TimeRemainingElement` is located in the `Grid` named ***"TimeTextGrid"*** which is in the second row of the `Grid` named ***"MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Grid"***. And the `Slider` named ***"ProgressSlider"*** is in the first row. So to put `TimeRemainingElement` on the left of the Slider, we can add a `Grid` in the first row, then remove `TimeRemainingElement` and `ProgressSlider` to the different columns of the new grid like:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeRemainingElement"
               Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
               Text="00:00" />
    <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Height="33"
            MinWidth="80"
            Margin="12,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False"
            Style="{StaticResource MediaSliderStyle}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeElapsedElement"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
               Text="00:00" />
</Grid>
```

And set the `Visibility` of `TimeTextGrid` to `Collapsed` like:

```
<Grid x:Name="TimeTextGrid"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Height="15"
      Margin="12,0"
      Visibility="Collapsed">
    <!--<TextBlock x:Name="TimeElapsedElement"
               Margin="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
               Text="00:00" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeRemainingElement"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
               Text="00:00" />-->
</Grid>
```

Here we can't delete `TimeTextGrid`. Missing `TimeTextGrid` would cause exception is some scenarios.

> make the time show as **00:00** not 0:00:00

Changing the format of elapsed and remaining time is not easy. They are set in code-behind, just editing properties of `TimeElapsedElement` or `TimeRemainingElement` won't work. And I'm not sure why you need them show as "00:00". What if the media's duration is large than one hour? How to show a time that is "2:10:20"? I'd suggest you just use the original format, but if you do want to show it like "00:00", here is a workaround:

Firstly, we need to create a Format Converter to convert the time format like following:

```
public class TimeSpanFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(value.ToString());

            return timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            return "00:00";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then as the `Text` of `TimeElapsedElement` and `TimeRemainingElement` are set in code-behind, we can't use `TimeSpanFormatConverter` in `TimeElapsedElement` and `TimeRemainingElement` directly. So I add two `TextBlock`s and bind their `Text` property to the `Text` of `TimeElapsedElement` and `TimeRemainingElement` and use `TimeSpanFormatConverter` in my new `TextBlock` like:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTimeRemaining"
           Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
           Text="{Binding Text,
                          Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter},
                          ElementName=TimeRemainingElement}" />
```

The `StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter` is defined as

```
<local:TimeSpanFormatConverter x:Key="TimeSpanFormatConverter" />
```

After this, I can hide `TimeTextGrid` and use my `TextBlock`s in `MyGrid`:

```
<Grid x:Name="MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTimeRemaining"
                   Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Text,
                                  Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter},
                                  ElementName=TimeRemainingElement}" />
        <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider"
                Style="{StaticResource MediaSliderStyle}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Height="33"
                MinWidth="80"
                Margin="12,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTimeElapsedElement"
                   Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="{Binding Text,
                                  Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter},
                                  ElementName=TimeElapsedElement}" />
    </Grid>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="BufferingProgressBar"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Height="4"
                 Margin="0,2,0,0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 IsHitTestVisible="False"
                 IsIndeterminate="True"
                 Visibility="Collapsed" />

    <Grid x:Name="TimeTextGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Height="15"
          Margin="12,0"
          Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TimeElapsedElement"
                   Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Text="00:00" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TimeRemainingElement"
                   Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Text="00:00" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

> Is it possible to remove the "Cast to Device" icon/option from the MediaTransportControls?

To remove the "Cast to Device" icon/option from the MediaTransportControls, we can just delete the `AppBarButton` named ***"CastButton"*** in ***"MediaControlsCommandBar"*** :

```
<!--<AppBarButton x:Name="CastButton"
              Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
              MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="7">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC15;" />
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>-->
```

And finally, after these changes, the `MediaTransportControls` will look like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Awesome solution! Do you have any idea how to solve this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538161/running-background-audio-in-different-pages-of-uwp-app/37538724#37538724